# Constants in dozer mappings

Tags: java, dozer

does anybody know how to put a constant value into an attribute with dozer? I haven't seen anything about that in the dozer's documentation

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure what you mean - if you want Dozer to always populate BeanB.someField with a constant whenever you map from BeanA to BeanB?

You might want to register a [custom converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html) for this mapping.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. I was wondering if it was possible to do it directly without a custom converter.

Comment: I believe your only methods are to use a custom convert or to do it by hand when you invoke Dozer. Dozer only really handles mapping from one bean to another, and doesn't give you much room to insert other logic (which makes sense, as it isn't meant to do that).

Answer (score 2):

How about taking advantage of the events mechanism?

So you could register a listener which would do the setting of the value in `mappingFinished()` of your listener.
Consult [dozer doc on events](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/events.html) for details. Of course you would have to guard the setting code with some kind of `if ... instanceof` condition.

Comment: This worked really well for me, though I put my hook on `preWritingDestinationValue`, so the values act as defaults, rather than overriding what's already been mapped.

Answer (score 1):

Recent builds of dozer make this easier.  You can specify both custom converters *and* you can specify parameters to that converter for a given field mapping.  It should be trivial to create a single 'ConstantConverter' that will take an input parameter and put that in the output field 100% of the time.

Comment: Actually it's not that easy with custom converters. You would either need to write a converter for the whole class containing the field (which defeats the purpose of using dozer in the first place) or monkey around with ugly solutions to attach a converter to a single field (and that field only exists on one of the classes). It might be a good approach in some cases though (depending on how your objects are structured).

Answer (score 1):

One possible implementation is:

```
public class ConstantsCustomConvertor implements ConfigurableCustomConverter{

    private String pararamter;
    @Override
    public Object convert(Object existingDestinationFieldValue, Object sourceFieldValue, Class<?> destinationClass, Class<?> sourceClass) {     
        return pararamter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameter(String parameter) {
        this.pararamter = parameter;

    }
}
```

Example:

```
<field custom-converter-param="CONTANT_VALUE" custom-converter="org.yourcompany.ConstantsCustomConvertor">
    <a>a-class-dummyfieldname</a>
    <b>b-class-fieldname</b>
</field>
```

This Custom Convertor is assumes that the b-class-fieldname is of type String.

Comment: Might be clearer to rename this as `OneWayConstantConverter`. Could also consider throwing an exception if the mapping is attempted the other way round (i.e. not in a one-way mapping).

Comment: I've now posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858519/57803731#answer-57803731) that does it in a similar way but ensure it is only used in a one-way mapping and uses `class` as the source field to eliminate the need for a dummy field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to do this in a one-way mapping, the following will work for a String constant:

```
/**
 * Custom one-way Dozer converter mapping to constant string value specified by a parameter.
 */
public class OneWayStringConstantConverter extends DozerConverter<Class, String> {

    public OneWayBooleanConstantConverter() {
        super(Class.class, String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertTo(Class aClass, String aString) {
        // Return constant value specified by the parameter (source is ignored)
        return getParameter();
    }

    @Override
    public Class convertFrom(String aString, Class aClass) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "OneWayStringConstantConverter should only be used in one-way mappings");
    }
}
```

... invoked by:

```
  <field custom-converter="full.path.to.OneWayStringConstantConverter"
         custom-converter-param="My constant string value">
     <a>class</a> <!-- Source not used: Converter only sets target of a one-way mapping -->
     <b>targetField</b>
  </field>
```

Would recommend using the `class` value as a dummy "source field" since it is not used yet `getClass()` method is guaranteed to exist on any object.

I needed to do it for a Boolean instead so used this:

```
/**
 * Custom one-way Dozer converter which maps to the constant boolean value (true or false)
 * specified by a parameter.
 */
public class OneWayBooleanConstantConverter extends DozerConverter<Class, Boolean> {

    public OneWayBooleanConstantConverter() {
        super(Class.class, Boolean.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertTo(Class aClass, Boolean aBoolean) {
        // Return constant boolean value specified by the parameter (source is ignored)
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(getParameter());
    }

    @Override
    public Class convertFrom(Boolean aBoolean, Class aClass) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "OneWayBooleanConstantConverter should only be used in one-way mappings");
    }
}
```